# Find All XmlNodes that has a particular attribute

Tags: asp.net, xml, xpath

I have this XML document:

```
<root>
  <node1 id="field2"/>
  <node2 id="field3"/>
  <node3>
    <node4 id="field4"/>
  </node3>
</root>
```

where the common thing is the attribute named id. I would like to get all the nodes that has an attribute named "id" - regardless of level. In this example i would end up with a list of the nodes: node1, node2, node4.

Normally i would try an xpath like this: "//[@id]" but im getting an error saying that it need to return a node set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XPath:

```
//node()[@id]
```